# What's the equivalent of ViewPort in WinRT XAML?

Tags: html, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, viewport

What would be the equivalent to the following line of code, but in XAML?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; user-scalable=false;">
```

I want my app to be portable and be "good enough" to look regardless of the user's monitor. At the same time I am not keen on spending too much time on targeting diverse screen resolution that deviates from norm.

Is there a way to simply scale the content of an XAML app like I could a web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent. In some Scenarios, [Viewbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.viewbox) is a good replacement.
But in my opinion you should reconsider your approach because it won't be "good enough", especially when dealing with touch and [touch target sizes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465415.aspx). You may also encounter usability issues when the user wants to use your app side by side with other apps (split screen).